# show custom form field value on all pages of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I created a custom form on the home page of wordpress site. I  want to get these form value on header for every pages where user go.
Example: user select his location this selected location show visited pages.

Comment: How about showing some code and what you've done so far?

Comment: session_start();    
     var_dump($_SESSION['city'] =  $_GET['city']);
I added this code in header.php file for display value of all pages on header.

Comment: please help me.

Comment: We need the code of the header. Where is the field shown, what does it do, etc. Please be as complete as possible in what you're trying to achieve, and what you have done so far to try and achieve that.

Comment: Thanks you for reply its working fine using session in wordpres  header.php file